# Python C/API How can I generate a module object from a code object compiled by Py_CompileString without using PyImport_ExecCodeModule?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I could have used PyImport_ExecCodeModule directly to generate a module object. However, what I want is to get it when it is not executed.
Execution is the key, I don't accept it.
In fact, my ultimate goal is to embed some C++ functions in a python module using pybind11 before executing the module. Like this：

```
C/C++
const char *myCode="print('hello world')";
PyObject* codeObject=Py_CompileString(myCode, "", Py_file_input);
pybind11::module module=py::reinterpret_steal<pybind11::module>(PyImport_ExecCodeModule("1", codeObject);
module.def("func1", [](){});
module.def("func2", [](){});
......
```

Now I want the definition about "func1" and "func2" to be in front of PyImport_ExecCodeModule, that way I can call "func1" and "func2" in my python code.

note: I know the API "pybind11::exec", but I can't call it because of something. I must get a module object but not execute the python code.
what should I do?

```
C/C++
const char *myCode="print('hello world')";
PyObject* codeObject=Py_CompileString(myCode, "", Py_file_input);
pybind11::module module=py::reinterpret_steal<pybind11::module>(PyImport_ExecCodeModule("1", codeObject);
module.def("func1", [](){});
module.def("func2", [](){});
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`PyImport_AddModule`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c.PyImport_AddModule) to create a module instance inadvance?

```cpp
pybind11::module module = py::reinterpret_steal<pybind11::module>(PyImport_AddModule("1"));
module.def("func1", [](){});
module.def("func2", [](){});

const char *myCode = "print('hello world')";
// const char *myCode = "func1()";
PyObject* codeObject=Py_CompileString(myCode, "", Py_file_input);
module = py::reinterpret_steal<pybind11::module>(PyImport_ExecCodeModule("1", codeObject));
```